# Creating Metavariables in Prolog

Tags: prolog, metaprogramming

I am working with implementing a unification algorithm for a term rewriting system in Prolog. To fully implement this, I need a predicate substituting out a given subterm for another term. Unfortunately, the way that Prolog instantiates fresh variables prevents the system from successfully be able to achieve this. I have some built in operators, star and divi (really just representing the * and / symbols, but in prefix form). My substitute predicate is made up of the following predicates:

```
replace(A,B, [], []).
replace(A,B, [H|T], [B|T2]) :- (H==A)->replace(A, B, T, T2).
replace(A,B, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- (H\==A)->replace(A, B, T, T2).

replace_lst([], [H|T], [H2|T2]).
replace_lst([H1|T1], [H|T], [H2|T2]) :- 
    arg(1,H1,X),
    arg(2,H1,Y),
    replace(X,Y,[H|T],[H2|T2]),
    replace_lst(T1,[H|T],[H2|T2]).

substitute([H|T],A,X):-
    A=..List,
    replace_lst([H|T],List,C),
    X=..C.
```

Where this runs into trouble is that, for instance, the terms star(X,X) and star(Y,Y), are, by the logic of my rewrite system, structurally equivalent and require no such substitution. However, comparing these two terms using the unifiable predicate will lead Prolog to attempting unification for the two, and the resulting term is no longer equivalent in structure to the original star(X,X) structure. Therefore, I attempted to check for term equality through their structure, but this leads to another can of worms in which, for instance, my rewrite system contains the rewrite rule:

star(X,X)==>X.

However,attempting to substitute based on the variant equality =@= operator leads to the issue of Prolog seeing two differently instantiated terms with the same structure as the same term. Therefore, defining a variant-based subtitution predicate like so:

```
variant_replace(A,B, [], []).
variant_replace(A,B, [H|T], [B|T2]) :- (H=@=A)->variant_replace(A, B, T, T2).
variant_replace(A,B, [H|T], [H|T2]) :- (H\=@=A)->variant_replace(A, B, T, T2).

variant_replace_lst([], [H|T], [H2|T2]).
variant_replace_lst([H1|T1], [H|T], [H2|T2]) :- 
    arg(1,H1,X),
    arg(2,H1,Y),
    variant_replace(X,Y,[H|T],[H2|T2]),
    variant_replace_lst(T1,[H|T],[H2|T2]).


variant_substitute([H|T],A,X):-
    A=..List,
    variant_replace_lst([H|T],List,C),
    X=..C.
```

Leads to an issue where if I have some term:

```
star((star(X,Y),star(A,B))
```

and I want to substitute the star(X,Y) subterm with the following predicate:

```
?- variant_substitute([star(X,Y)=hole],star(star(X,Y),star(A,B)),D).
D = star(hole, hole) .
```

We can see Prolog, by the logic of the variant substitution predicate, will simply check for terms of a given structure, disregarding the actual variable instantiation. Therefore, I need a way to declare variables. What I desire is to have a system that is able to use metavariables declared in such a way each given term has up to N unique variables, ranging in value from V(0) to V(N-1). Ideally, such a system of metavariables would look like so:

```
 substitute([star(v(0),v(1))=hole],star(star(v(0),v(1)),star(v(2),v(3))),D).
D = star(hole, star(v(2), v(3)))
```

I need Prolog to see terms denoted with v(#) as variables since I will need to use the unifiable predicate down the road to compare them to the original declaration of my rewrite rules, which is declared like so :

```
star(X,X) ==> X.
divi(X,X) ==>  X.
divi(star(X,Y),Y) ==>  X.
star(divi(X,Y),Y) ==>  X.
star(X, star(Y,Z)) ==> star(star(divi(X,Z),Y),Z).
divi(X, star(Y,Z)) ==> star(divi(divi(X,Z),Y),Z).
star(X, divi(Y,Z)) ==> divi(star(star(X,Z),Y),Z).
divi(X, divi(Y,Z)) ==> divi(divi(star(X,Z),Y),Z).
```

What would be the best way to implement this format of metavariable in Prolog?

Comment: Do you know one-sided unification? [`subsumes_term/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#subsumes_term) tests this property.

Comment: I suppose this would get over the problem of prolog attempting to unify two structurally equivalent terms on both sides. Is there a way to get back a unifier? Obviously, for unifiable we are able to get back the unifier for the two terms, however subsumes_term seems to only check for if the two terms are unifiable without giving back the unifier

Comment: What do you mean by unifier, exactly? It should be trivial to produce